# Email app syncing two years old messages

Tags: applications, sync, email, stock-email-app

OK, I have maybe quite a silly quiestion, but could you recommend email app that does this:

- Show emails from the latest month/week, then delete them from phone memory (unless I want to sync them again)
- If I delete email in my phone, it is deleted in my account as well (meaning trasferred to "Deleted emails").
- Ad free and reliable (I do not want to put my account info into just any app)

Default email app would be great, unless everytime it starts syncing old unread emails from 2013!! I could not find anywhere in the settings to sync just last week/month. It's driving me nuts it is missing...(or I am missing sth)

My provider uses basic smtp/pop3 servers, I have CM12.1 (Lollipop).

Thanks for suggestions :)

Edit:
I have tried:
Inbox - not working with non-Google account
Gmail app - no setting "Days of mail to sync" for non-Google account.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575). With the correct phrasing and details provided, you might try your luck at [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Gmail or Inbox?

- You can choose the threshold before which date, the emails won't be synced.
- If you delete email from phone, they will get deleted in the respective account too.
- Its Ad free and reliable.

P.S. you can also add other email accounts than like yahoo/outlook in the Gmail app.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, it is my fathers phone and I had no access to it. Anyway, to your suggestion - Inbox app does not let me to use non-Google account.
Gmail app - this would be good, there is "Days of mail to sync" setting under Data usage. But this setting is only in my Google account again. For my non-Google account this setting is missing and it starts downloading 2 years old messages...
Is there any other suitable app? I have tested it on Windows Phone and there it works with built-in application...